# How to get the row number which satisfies a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in an Excel sheet having three columns. one column contains the person name, 2nd column contain the company name and 3rd column contains the city name.

```
Name    Company City
abc     mn      C1
asd     th      C2
qwe     mn      C1
aqw     kj      C1
ert     mn      C2
```

Here I have written a macro in Excel 2007/2010 to get the person's names that are working for company "mn" and are in "C1" city.

Can anybody help me out???

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? If not, Pivot tables can do this for you without any programming!!!

Comment: Sure - what have you tried?  Post your existing code for suggestions.

Comment: When you say "get" the person's names, you need to be specific. Do you wish to list them on another sheet? Do you wish to hide everything but these? Do you wish to get the row numbers in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just sort the area by Company and then by City is the easiest way to discover the employees. But something like this should work too:

```
Sub SearchEmployeeByCompanyAndCity(company As String, city As String, start As Range)
    Dim i, j As Integer
    i = 1
    j = 1
    While (start.Cells(i, j).Value <> "")
        If start.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = company And start.Cells(i, j + 2).Value = city Then
            MsgBox start.Cells(i, j)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Sub Test()
    SearchEmployeeByCompanyAndCity "mn", "C1", Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: I still prefer just sort the columns :-)

Comment: Note that you are declaring i as a `variant`. I think you want it to be an `integer`. Change your declaration to: `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer`

Answer (score 0):

If the table is in the top right of `Sheet1` like this:

[image]

The a macro like this will suffice - but there are lots of other ways of doing this - the most simple being a `Pivot Table` !

```
Option Explicit

Sub FINDemployees()

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim cell
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp))
        If LCase(cell(1, 2)) = "mn" And LCase(cell(1, 3)) = "c1" Then
            MsgBox cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```